# Give subcategories in second select label after selecting first select label

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am new at learning Ajax and I use PHP MYSQLI.I have 2 select labels and I want if 1st choise was made, in the second select label give subcategoriies of that selected option. For example if selected BMW give all models that concern to BMW. I wrote code here but I don't know why it doesn't work. [2 select labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsNxE.png) Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{ $(function() {
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'ajax.php',
 data: {
  'get_option':val
 },
 success: function (response) {
 $("#new_select").html(response); 
 }
 });
});
}

</script>
```

Here is main page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="select_box" class="form-control" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
            <option disabled selected>1ci Kateqoriya</option>
            <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL";
            $select_box = $db->select($query);
            ?>
          <?php while($row = $select_box->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name_az']; ?></option>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="new_select" class="form-control" >
          <option disabled selected>2ci Kateqoriya</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is ajax.php:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
 $p_id = $_POST['get_option'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id ='$p_id'";
    $ch_cat = $db->select($query);    
 while($row=$ch_cat->fetch_assoc())
 {
  echo "<option>".$row['name_az']."</option>";
 }
 exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested the code but I think this should work. Instead of fetching only options via ajax, fetch the whole select box like this. So your ajax.php will be -

```
    <?php 

if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
    $p_id = $_POST['get_option'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id ='$p_id'";
    $ch_cat = $db->select($query);   
    echo "<select id='new_select' class='form-control' onchange=\"fetch_select2(this.value);\" > \n";
    while($row=$ch_cat->fetch_assoc())
    {
     echo "<option>".$row['name_az']."</option>";
    }
    exit;
   }
   echo "</select>\n";

?>
```

Main page:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="select_box" class="form-control" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
            <option disabled selected>1ci Kateqoriya</option>
            <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL";
            $select_box = $db->select($query);
            ?>
          <?php while($row = $select_box->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name_az']; ?></option>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="slect2" onchange="fetch_select2(this.value);">
        <select id="new_select" class="form-control" >
          <option disabled selected>2ci Kateqoriya</option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="slect3">
        <select id="new_select2" class="form-control" >
          <option disabled selected>2ci Kateqoriya</option>

        </select>
    </div>        
</div>
```

and script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch_select(val)
    { $(function() {
     $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax.php',
     data: {
      'get_option':val
     },
     success: function (response) {
     $("#select2").html(response); 
     }
     });
    });
    }

    function fetch_select2(val)
    { $(function() {
     $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax2.php',
     data: {
      'get_option':val
     },
     success: function (response) {
     $("#select3").html(response); 
     }
     });
    });
    }        

</script>
```

Comment: but how can i do it for 3rd select? after selecting 2nd?

Comment: Updated the answer to accomodate for third select box.  You will have to write a file similar to ajax.php and call it ajax2.php to populate third select box.

Comment: can't I write it on ajax.php? Need I create new one?